# Element not taking string values

Tags: javascript, html, element

I have a html page containing two textboxes with id name and mobile.

I've created a list and inserted the values into it.But its not taking the name value, its only taking the mobile textbox value. The other part is shown as undefined.

This is the code.

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.textContent = name.value +" , "+mobile.value;
list.appendChild(li);
```

What is the error ?

Comment: I would assume the issue is somewhere else: Show us how you are defining `name`?

Comment: <input type="text" id="name" required="required">

this is how i defined the name textbox.i dont think the problem is with defining...its showing undefined only when i assign it to li element.

Answer (score 1):

"name" is a poor name for a field since if you do not qualify is like document.getElementsByName("name")[0] it could be window.name -

If the field has id="name" then use document.getElementById("name") instead since most browsers do not copy the ID attribute to the window scope

Thus

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.textContent = document.getElementById("name").value +" , "+
  document.getElementById("mobile").value; 
list.appendChild(li);
```

I also personally prefer li.innerHTML since it works in all browsers

Lastly remember that IDs must be unique